# The smallest base $b$ for which the fraction $\frac{5445469}{5445468}$ has a finite number of decimal digits

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Recently, I have found this problem:

> Given the fraction $\frac{5445469}{5445468}$, find the smallest base $b\;\in\;\mathbf{N}$ such that, in base $b$, the fraction has a finite number of decimal digits.
> To solve this problem, I have splitted the fraction into two terms as follows:
> $$\frac{5445469}{5445468}=\frac{5445468}{5445468}+\frac{1}{5445468}=1+\frac{1}{5445468}$$
> Now, the first term is a $1$, so in every base it's always $1$ as the numerator of the fraction. We have to find the minimu base for which $\frac{1}{5445468}$ has a finite number of terms.

I know the factorization of $5445468$ that is:
$$5445468=2^2\cdot3^4\cdot7^5$$
but how can we get $b$?
I think that in order to have a finite decimal representation, $5445468$ in base $b$ has to be multiple of $2$ and $5$. Is it correct?

Comment: I think the "decimal" in there is only meant figuratively, since there's no nice term for "base $b$ digits".

Comment: $2,5$ only have special significance in base $10$.  For instance $\left(\frac 13\right)_{10}=.1_3$.

Comment: When saying "decimnal digits", do you mean "$b$-adic digits"?

Answer (score 5):

In base $10$ the fractions with a finite number of (nonzero) decimal (base $10$) digits are those whose denominators are divisible only by the primes $2$ and $5$.

In base $b \ldots$.

Can you finish?

Answer (score 4):

$$
\frac{1}{5445468}=
\frac{1}{2^2\cdot3^4\cdot7^5}=
\frac{2^3\cdot3^1\cdot7^0}{2^5\cdot3^5\cdot7^5}=
\frac{24}{42^5}=
(0\,.\,0:0:0:0:24)_{42}
$$
has finite representation in base $42$.

Now this fraction has finite representation in base $B$ iff
$$
\frac{1}{5445468}=\frac{A}{B^n}
$$
This implies $B^n= 5445468 A$ and so each prime divisor of $5445468$ divides $B$. Therefore, $B$ is at least $2\cdot3\cdot7=42$.

Comment: Why is it the smallest, though?

Comment: You need one factor of each prime that is a factor of the denominator.  If $b=2\cdot 3 \cdot 7, b^4=2^4 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 7^4$ and $5445468$ will divide evenly into it, so there will be four places in the expansion.  Compare with the fact that in base $10=2 \cdot 5$, 80=2^4 \cdot 5$ has a terminating decimal that is four places long.